# Record count for Excel file with extension CSV

Tags: c#

I am trying to count the record of excel file with extension csv with the following code but I am not getting exact number of rows.

```
int lineCount = 0;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@fileFullPath))
{
    while (reader.ReadLine()!= null)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please advise me on this.

Comment: What's wrong with just `int lineCount = File.ReadLines(@fileFullPath).Count();` ?

Comment: Excel files are *not* CSVs, they are ZIP packages that contain XML files. CSV files are plain text files. `File.ReadAllLines()` will return a string[] array with all lines. You can count them with `thatArray.Length`. `ReadLines` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` whose count you can get with `.Count()`

Comment: As for `am not getting exact number of rows` what does this mean? This should return the actual number of lines. It may be off by one, but that's it. Did you want to ignore header lines perhaps?

Comment: Could the OP mean columns?

Comment: CSV files can use more than one line per record (if the record contains multiline text), so simply counting the lines in the file is not sufficient. I suggest using some (free) 3rd-party CSV reader library instead.

Comment: ☝ Additionally to Uwe Keim, I can recommend `CsvHelper`: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@fileFullPath).Length
```

Comment: @Rango what issue? The OP didn't describe any issue and that's not the OP's code. If anything `ReadAllLines` needs more memory because it reads the entire file in memory. The OP's code should just work

Comment: CSV files can use more than one line per record (if the record contains multiline text), so simply counting the lines in the file is not sufficient.

Comment: `var lineCount = File.ReadLines(@fileFullPath).Count();` - we don't want to load *all* the file into RAM

Answer (score 0):

First try to open the mentioned `.csv` file using notepad. If the file opens and readable, It means that your file is human readable and it can be read by File reader line by line without further processing.

If it is so you can use `var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@fileFullPath).Length`. Otherwise you need to have library for reading Excel file

Comment: The OP's code should work if the file is an actual text file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos CSV files can use more than one line per record (if the record contains multiline text), so simply counting the lines in the file is _not_ sufficient. Better use a 3rd-party CSV reader library instead.

Comment: @UweKeim right now we have no idea what the OP wants, not even if the files are CSV or xlsx. It could be that some fields contain newlines or it could be that the OP wanted to exclude headers or empty lines. For a complex file, yes, something like CsvHelper would be needed